# 3D UML Modeling in JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, 3d, uml

I would like to create an web-based application for modeling UML diagrams in 3D. I mean something like this [3D UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0jjC.jpg). I can use JavaScript (or TypeScript or something like that) and CSS3 and HTML5. But I still dont know what JS library should I use. I found for example "threejs" and "away3d". Do you know some suitable library for my purposes ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Css3d renderer in Threejs might be useful you can apply all your css3 property and also you get markup language in your developer tool where you can see all Css3d transformation happening look at their demo of periodic table
[CSS3d Periodic table](https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you know about CSS3 3D transforms. Using only CSS3 can be a little harder for your purposes, but it is very viable to do, if you do not exaggerate with several elements in 3D, because CSS3 transforms are intended to be used with moderation.

The threejs is intended to be used together with HTML5 Canvas and WebGL. If you want to use WebGL, which is very powerful to do complex things in 3D, instead of CSS3 3D transforms that is much more simple, threejs is a good choice, because WebGL do not have native operations on transformation matrices, I think.

But if you want CSS3 3D transforms, which I think is a good idea to you, just remember: avoid mix of CSS declaration in JavaScript, is a bad practice mix HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. You can change the class of an element HTML (that can be a class in your application) dinamically. In these classes you will do CSS declarations, with transitions, transformations, etc, instead of changing the .style property of an element on script.

I do not know if this will help you.

Comment: I was thinking about CSS3 transforms, but Im not sure its hardware accelerated. And why do you think CSS3 transforms are better choice for me?

Comment: I think that is a good choice if you want to do a UI in 3D for web-based application. Any interface with a set of 3D elements can use it. Of course, in a fully 3D scenario, use WebGL.
Browsers usually have great performace in CSS3 transforms,
but it is only my opinion, and I do not know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I want to create UML diagrams, not just UI so I think I should use WebGL. But what library? Babylon.js looks good, but Three.js also. I dont know what to choose.